# More efficient way for: value_counts (in %) for many columns grouped by a variable

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, frequency

I am working on a use case where I have many observations of many features per id and I need to count the frequency of values (~5 discrete values) for each id per column.

I have a solution for it which works for a fairly small dataset (e.g. < 1million rows) but fails on my whole dataset (which might get even larger in the future) since it fills my RAM. I could not find a clean groupby solution since I need to do it for many columns at once.

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100     # Number of features
m = 100     # Number of classes
k = 10000   # number of occurrences per class

possible_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df = []
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):
        df.append( np.append(i, np.random.choice(possible_values, n)) )

features = [f"feature{i}" for i in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=(["id"] + features))
```

It is easy enough without the groupby case:

```
df[features].apply(pd.value_counts).T / df.shape[0]
```

**My approach**

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars="id", var_name='feature', value_name='value')
feature_freq_id = pd.crosstab(index=[melted.id, melted.feature], columns=melted.value).reset_index()
feature_freq_id[possible_values] = feature_freq_id[possible_values].div(feature_freq_id[possible_values].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

The problem is that `melted` has `n*m*k` rows. My dataset has >250 features, >200 ids and ~5k observations per id which means that `melted` will have >250 mil rows. This results in my memory being eventually filled and python dies.

**Expected result:**

```
feature_freq_id.head(3)
```

|  | id | feature | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | feature0 | 0.183 | 0.185 | 0.226 | 0.187 | 0.219 |
| 1 | 0 | feature1 | 0.178 | 0.222 | 0.209 | 0.209 | 0.182 |
| 2 | 0 | feature10 | 0.215 | 0.213 | 0.175 | 0.196 | 0.201 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: Use `groupby` over `id` in combination with your "easy" method:

```
def fractions(sdf):
    return sdf.apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True).fillna(0.).T
    
result = df.groupby("id")[features].apply(fractions)
result.index.set_names("feature", level=1, inplace=True)
```

This should avoid the memory `melt`-down?

Comment: That works pretty well and did certainly solve the meltdown. I was hoping that pandas has a build in function for it (which is how I found crossstab). I purposefully try to avoid apply() recently due to having some runtime problems with unfortunate calculations inside it before. But I should at least have tried it I guess.

Comment: @Nickkon Thanks for the feedback! I understand your `apply`-reluctance. It is a handy tool, but has potential to underperform compared to methods that are _nearer to vectorization_ (whatever that means). I'd say it's okay here, since it only distributes a native Pandas-function over the columns.